# Как убрать рамку вокруг полноэкранного окна tkitner?

Tags: python, tkinter

Окно открыт в полноэкранном режиме с помощью команды

```
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```

, вокруг окна есть окантовка белой рамкой толщиной в 1 пиксель. Как его убрать?

UPD. Нашел решение, необходимо выставить highlightthickness canvas`a на 0:
can = Canvas(highlightthickness=0)

[image: На белом фоне этого не видно, но когда это окно открыт на весь экран, по периметру его окаймляет белая рамка толщиной в 1 пиксель, примерно.]

Comment: Попробуйте так: `root.overrideredirect(True)`

Comment: Попробовал, теперь при запуске выкидывает ошибку:
_tkinter.TclError: can`t set fullscreen attribute for ".": ovveride-redirect flag is set.
Не совмещаются эти два флага, поэтому убрал
self.root.attributes('-fullscreen', True) 
Все так же, рамка на месте,дальше изменил (добавил +5 к размерам экрана):
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(root.winfo_screenwidth()+5, root.winfo_screenheight()+5))
Вот после этого рамки исчезли правая и нижняя рамки, остались сверху и слева

Comment: UPD. Нашел решение, необходимо выставить highlightthickness canvas`a на 0:
can = Canvas(highlightthickness=0)